# Evaluate preprocessor directives in C

Tags: c, preprocessor

I have a question about C preprocessor.
I have define the macros:

```
#define num2str(x)      str(x)

#define str(x) #x
```

and I pass a number to a string constant:

```
const   char    myString[]     = num2str(NUMBER);
```

When I put for example `#define NUMBER 10` works fine.
But I want to put `num2str(NUMBER + 10)`, and the result is "10 + 10" instead of "20".
Is there any way to evaluate the expression NUMBER+10 and obtain "20"?

Comment: `Is there *any* way..` Use something else then C preprocessor. Like `m4`.

Comment: While the C preprocessor does have the capability to evaluate certain simple constant expressions, those results are only usable in preprocessor expressions such as `#if` expressions.  I don't know of a way to actually have the evaluated results placed into the preprocessor output.

Answer (score 1):

In C, macro replacement does not do arithmetic.

There are some kludges that can implement limited arithmetic. Determining whether such a kludge would serve your purpose requires further information about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are text substitutions<sup>1</sup>, nothing more.  Macro arguments are not evaluated, they are simply expanded in place.

---

1. Strictly speaking they’re *token* substitutions, but the distinction is pretty minor in this case.